# How can I access IPython's "display" function?

Tags: python, ipython, display

I tried this code, expecting it to use IPython's `display` function:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])
 
display(data.head(10))
```

But I get an error message that says `NameError: name 'display' undefined`. Why? How do I make it so that I can use `display`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: The normal Python3 display is : `print(data)`.  Or in an interactive session just type `data`.

Comment: This question became relevant when I used VSCode to convert .ipynb to .py. The line `from IPython.display import display` was needed.

Answer (score 67):

`display` is a function in the `IPython.display` module that runs the appropriate dunder method to get the appropriate data to ... display.  If you really want to run it

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

display(data.head(10))
```

But don't.  IPython is already doing that for you.  Just do:

```
data.head(10)
```

---

You even might have IPython uninstalled, try:

```
pip install IPython
```

or if running pip3:

```
pip3 install IPython
```

Comment: Shouldn't the solution be on top to avoid confusion? "IPython is already doing that for you. Just do:..."

Comment: Under Jupyter, `display` is quite use full as its notably if you use `pandas`, when you need to display multiple objets: `display`produces the full representation where `print`   bings only the text one.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the problem on pycaret, you have to open the below file -

```
..\env\Lib\site-packages\pycaret\datasets.py
```

and add the line of code  -

```
from IPython.display import display
```