# VS Code: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Tried to import `pandas` in VS Code with

```
import pandas
```

and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\hello\sqltest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Tried to install `pandas` with

```
pip install pandas

pip3 install pandas

python -m pip install pandas
```

separately which returned

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xxxx\hello> pip3 install pandas

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\xxxx\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\xxxx\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\xxxx\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\xxxx\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\xxxx\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

Tried:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

and got

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xxxx\hello> sudo pip install pandas

sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sudo pip install pandas
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sudo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also tried to change the python path under workspace settings following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107016/11901732). with `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` which is the python path I found in Command Prompt using `where python` but didn't work.

Then I tried

```
python -m venv .venv
```

which returned

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xxxx\hello> python -m venv .venv

Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\hello\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe'
```

---

Update:

Tried

```
python3.8.5 -m pip install pandas
```

and returned

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xxxx\hello> python3.8.5 -m pip install pandas

python3.8.5 : The term 'python3.8.5' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3.8.5 -m pip install pandas
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3.8.5:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install pandas`? Or `python3.x -m pip install pandas`?

Comment: Or running it as `python3 file.py`?

Comment: Hi @MZ  please see the edited question; how to run it as `python3 file.py`?

Comment: Do python3 sqltest.py in the terminal

Comment: I didn’t mean a literal python3.x. I meant 3.(whatever python version you’re using) or just python3

Comment: @MZ So I tried with `python3.8.5` and tried to run `python3 sqltest.py` in terminal but didn't work either :/

Comment: Are you sure you're running the python file from the same virtual environment?

Comment: @po.pe I am not too sure about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems fairly simple! First things first though!

From looking at your post, you seem to have followed a guide into installing `Pandas`. Nothing is wrong about that but I must point out first based on your information that you provided to us, you seem to run **Windows Powershell** `PS C:\Users\xxxx\hello>` and `the error format matches Powershell`. Therefore, `sudo` isn't *recognized* because `sudo` is the admin command for `Unix-based` systems like `Debian, Ubuntu, and so on` which is why it's not a valid command!

But here's how to properly install: (I assume you're running Windows but if that's not the case, correct me and Ill give you the Unix version!)

1 - Windows key, search up `CMD` and run it as `administrator` this is important to avoid permissions issues!

2 - Run `pip3 install pandas` **OR** `python3 -m pip3 install pandas`

Answer (score 26):

It's easier than we imagine:

[image]

This image explains how to solve this problem.

Comment: in the latest version of vscode, it is moved to upper right corner

Comment: This solved for me as well!

Answer (score 6):

The problem (at least in my case) was that I have installed a package under the default Python version but I have set the interpreter for the different Python version in Visual Studio Code (VS Code).
There are 2 options to resolve this.

1. Change the VS Code Interpreter: VS Code -> View -> Command Palette... (Ctrl+Shift+P) -> Python: Select Interpreter -> select "Python: Select Interpreter" (or Enter) -> select an interpreter based on our chosen Python version under which you have installed the package.
2. Install package under the correct Python version which means to change your default Python version and repeat the process of installation again.
   To change your default Python version (for Windows 10):
   Right click on This PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings (in the right panel) -> Environment Variables -> System variables (the bottom part of the window) -> double-click on "Path" -> Select the 1st row for the wanted Python version and move it up and then do the same with the 2nd row. I recommend to restart (close and open again) your Command Prompt session if you want to see/work with the new default Python version.

Note on installation: Following command (in Command Prompt) worked for me:
pip3 install pandas --user

Comment: Option 1 solved it for me as well

Answer (score 5):

1. Download anaconda interpreter from this [link](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)
2. After installation, open anaconda prompt (anaconda3) and execute this code `conda install ipykernel`. It will install all necessary packages.
3. Restart vs code and change interpreter to base conda and voala!

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks. I ran it in Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) though. One thing I see is that it opens a Python exe command prompt, to show the results. Any way I can see the results in Visual Studio itself? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hmmm... It could be your file extension, if it ends with (.py) it will open on python.exe. Try changing it to (.ipynb).

Comment: Changing to ipynb didn't solve it. I am looking to see the results for the Python program in Visual Studio itself. Is that doable?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to have worked with

```
pip install pandas --user
```

in Command Prompt.

---

**Additional note:**

For `IPython.display`,

```
pip install IPython--user
```

in Command Prompt, then

```
from IPython.display import display
```

in VS Code.

**Helpful links:**

[pip  --user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/11901732)

[Display() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328495/11901732)

Answer (score 3):

I have just run VSCode as administrator!

Comment: This did it for me.

Comment: Worked for me, though I wonder why this was needed, and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and running the below command solved it:

```bash
pip3 install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: That's strange, I don't see how upgrading could solve this issue. What was your previous panda version and which one did you upgrade to? I have the same issue but already have the latest versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple versions of python installed and/or have something like acaconda installed, you'll have conflicts with the interpreter location in vscode.

To change the settings in vscode:

`Ctrl + P`
Search for `python: select interpreter` and then select 'recommended' option and it should work again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Anaconda, I've tried many things and only this worked for me.
In windows search, find "This PC", right click and click properties-> Advanced system settings -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment viriables -> Path
For me
Add or Edit Path to: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using vscode on ubuntu 22.04 with anaconda3. The solution for me was: Open settings, type `'python: default Interpreter Path'` and enter the path where the python executable is `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`