# How to display a styled panda dataframe over a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display a dataframe with a specific style twice (output twice on jupyter notebook). It doesn't show up when I use a for loop.

```
## having already created dataframe df

for i in range(2):
      df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border',
                                        '10px solid yellow')]}])
```

However it works when I do this:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border',
                                        '10px solid yellow')]}])

df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border',
                                        '10px solid yellow')]}])
```

How can I get it to work in a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display`:

```
for i in range(2):
  display(df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border',
                                    '10px solid yellow')]}]))
```

Comment: What package is display in?

Comment: `from IPython.display import display`,
but you don't need to import it if you are already in a jupyter notebook

Comment: Have a look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328495/536503

Answer (score 3):

By default, Jupyter cells only display the **last expression** output.

To change this behavior and display all expressions in a cell when you run it, you can add this line at the beginning of your notebook:

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"  # default='last_expr'
```